# How to use the Search Method in java mail api

Tags: java, search, jakarta-mail

I am using the javamail api to make a Search option which Searches the Emails in the Gmail Folder on the Basis of a Keyword present in the Subject of the Messages 
Here is the Code that i am Using

```
public class EGMail7 {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String m10 = "abc@gmail.com";   
    final String n10 = "12345";
    string host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
    try
    {
    Properties pro1 = new Properties();   
    pro1.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");    
    pro1.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    pro1.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
    pro1.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
    pro1.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");  
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(pro1, 
        new javax.mail.Authenticator()                  
{ 
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
{
        return new PasswordAuthentication(m10,n10);
        }
    }); 
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");  
    store.connect(host, m10, n10); 
    Folder folderbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    folderbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);   
    SearchTerm search = new SearchTerm(){

        @Override
        public boolean match(Message message) {
            try
            {
                if(message.getSubject().contains([Keyword]))  
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    Message[] found = folderbox.search(search);

    int length = found.length;
    for(int i = 0;i<found.length;i++)
    {
        Message mess1 = found[i];
        System.out.println("->Message Number > "+i);
        System.out.println("->Message Subject >"+mess1.getSubject());
    }
    folderbox.close(true);
    store.close();
}
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
   }
  }
```

I am using the Eclipse IDE and the problem i am facing is that whatever keyword I pass in the SearchTerm Method I always end up getting null Exception and an Message[] Found Array . I used Stack Trace to find out the Problem of this NullPointer Exception and it is at the line

```
Message[] found = folderbox.search(search);
```

I cannot Seem to understand what is the Problem Here ?

Regards,
Thank you

PS - and if someone could also please post the corrected code it would be great 
Thanks

Also When i Am Just Adding the Keyword Directly in the SearchTerm it give an Error like

```
SearchTerm searchCon = new SearchTerm([Keyword]);
```

There are 2 Errors
1.Cannot Instantiate the SearchTerm 
2.The Serializable class does not Declare a static final Serial Verison UID field of Type Long

So I Cannot Understand what is the Mistake here

Comment: And inside `.match()`, `message.getSubject()` does indeed return non-null for every message?

Comment: The Stack Trace at the inner Try catch inside the `.match()` is giving the NullPointer Exception and Pointing to the line `Message[] found = folderbox.search(search);`

Comment: But i do not seem to understand whatever Keywords that i am passing inside the `.match()` and `message.getSubject()` are  present in my INBOX in gmail and there are mails which actually contain the Keyword in their Subject

Comment: Can you please correct '(i+1)' . Your 'i' is increasing two by two.

Comment: Yes,Thank you for Pointing that out It has been Corrected

Comment: I even Tried Using the pop3 server instead of the imaps server which only has the Inbox folder The result was still the same NullPointer Exception at the same line and i still couldnt understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got exception because you have mail without subject. Statement should be corrected with ;

```
if(message.getSubject() != null && message.getSubject().contains([Keyword]))
```

Comment: Thank you So much for the Code , I am Not getting any errors now but it still cant seem to find my Emails and it takes atleast 15 minutes to return the Result

Comment: Any Suggestions on how the Program can give Results for the Desired Keyword because Subject containing that Keyword exists in the Inbox ,           Thank you

Comment: Because your inbox size is too big. Maybe better way to create multi thread search with specific date interval. Hope this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870045/java-imap-fetch-messages-since-a-date?lq=1 answer  will help you.

Comment: I will try out and let you Know

Comment: Thank You So much for the Link the Search Worked Perfectly and it was also Fast compared to Defining a Custom Search Term

Comment: Gmail [imap](https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-gmail-imap/) search w.r.t SubjectTerm Ex:[1](https://www.javatips.net/api/javax.mail.search.subjectterm#Example_5) [2](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.mail.search.SubjectTerm) or [range of Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/870658/5081877), [localized folder names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53387370/5081877)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is full of these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), please correct them.

There's no need to create your own custom SearchTerm, just use [SubjectTerm](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/search/SubjectTerm.html):

```
SearchTerm search = new SubjectTerm(keyword);
```

Comment: Thank you for the Link it was really helpful but is the response Time Faster than the Previous Approach because it takes at least 10 mins to come up with an output ?

Comment: and currently this does not seem to work in the Program , It gives an error when i remove the custom SearchTerm and directly add the keyword , Please Advice ??                                                                                                   Also if you could Write the Code and give it would be great                                Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's much faster because the search is done on the IMAP server instead of the client.  Exactly what error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry for the Late reply but the SearchTem is not directly Accepting the KeyWord and it is demanding for a custom Search term which returns a boolean value , I Tried to get it to work but it wont accept the Keyword , I am using Eclipse IDE if it makes any difference

Comment: What exactly does "is not directly accepting" mean?  What exactly are you doing?  Update your post with the new code and the exact error message.

Comment: The Question has been Edited with the Errors and also the Snippet that i am Using

Comment: First, `[Keyword]` is not valid Java syntax.  You need to use a constant String `"Keyword"` or a variable String `keyword`.  What version of JavaMail are you using?  You should be using at least [version 1.5.6](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release).

Comment: Yes sir The Keyword is being used as the Way specified by you, but the Version is old. I have updated the latest Version of the javamail api

Comment: Did that fix your problems?

Comment: Sorry Sir, It is Still Not recognizing the SearchTerm and Gives the same 2 Errors that have been mentioned in the Question even after Updating the Javamail api

Comment: I was able to Execute the Search of the Emails on the Basis of the date and No other Field of the Email Thanks to  newuserua_ext Link that he Provided

Comment: You're still doing something wrong, but unless you update the code in your original post, I can't tell what it is you're doing wrong.